# Running tests with coverage produced: FATAL ERROR in native method: processing of -javaagent failed

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, junit5

Solution: Thanks to the commitment from @Olga Klisho, the problem occurred due to special symbols in Windows userName.

Welcome community!

Any ideas?

I've encountered strange behavior while working on some tutorials with JUnit5 on Java11 JDK. 
Running all tests is Ok, but when trying to run all tests with the coverage I get this kind of error (below):

I'm running: 
InteliJ
JDK 11 
Maven 3.6.3
JUnit 5

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.6\bin\java.exe" -ea --illegal-access=permit --illegal-access=permit -javaagent:C:\Users\***\.IntelliJIdea2019.3\system\testAgent\intellij-coverage-agent-1.0.508.jar=C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\Temp\coverage11args -Didea.test.cyclic.buffer.size=1048576 "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3\lib\idea_rt.jar=62897:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3\lib\idea_rt.jar;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3\plugins\junit\lib\junit5-rt.jar;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3\plugins\junit\lib\junit-rt.jar;C:\Users\***\Desktop\Spring Boot Integration Testing\Section 5 Testing Java with JUnit5\testing-java-junit5-master\target\test-classes;C:\Users\***\Desktop\Spring Boot Integration Testing\Section 5 Testing Java with JUnit5\testing-java-junit5-master\target\classes;C:\Users\***\.m2\repository\javax\validation\validation-api\2.0.1.Final\validation-api-2.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\***\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-lang3\3.8.1\commons-lang3-3.8.1.jar;C:\Users\***\.m2\repository\org\junit\jupiter\junit-jupiter-api\5.3.1\junit-jupiter-api-5.3.1.jar;C:\Users\***\.m2\repository\org\apiguardian\apiguardian-api\1.0.0\apiguardian-api-1.0.0.jar;C:\Users\***\.m2\repository\org\opentest4j\opentest4j\1.1.1\opentest4j-1.1.1.jar;C:\Users\***\.m2\repository\org\junit\platform\junit-platform-commons\1.3.1\junit-platform-commons-1.3.1.jar;C:\Users\***\.m2\repository\org\junit\jupiter\junit-jupiter-engine\5.3.1\junit-jupiter-engine-5.3.1.jar;C:\Users\***\.m2\repository\org\junit\platform\junit-platform-engine\1.3.1\junit-platform-engine-1.3.1.jar;C:\Users\***\.m2\repository\org\assertj\assertj-core\3.14.0\assertj-core-3.14.0.jar;C:\Users\***\.m2\repository\org\junit\platform\junit-platform-launcher\1.3.1\junit-platform-launcher-1.3.1.jar" com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter -ideVersion5 -junit5 @w@C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\Temp\idea_working_dirs_junit.tmp @C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\Temp\idea_junit.tmp -socket62896
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
   at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
   at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndStartAgent(InstrumentationImpl.java:513)
   at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallPremain(InstrumentationImpl.java:525)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
   at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
   at com.intellij.rt.coverage.main.CoveragePremain.premain(CoveragePremain.java:35)
   at com.intellij.rt.coverage.main.CoveragePremain.premain(CoveragePremain.java:28)
   ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length 1
   at com.intellij.rt.coverage.instrumentation.Instrumentator.performPremain(Instrumentator.java:55)
   at com.intellij.rt.coverage.instrumentation.Instrumentator.premain(Instrumentator.java:33)
   ... 12 more
FATAL ERROR in native method: processing of -javaagent failed

Process finished with exit code 1
Exception in thread "main"
```

Here are my Maven dependencies and build:

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit-platform.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit-platform.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
            <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.14.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.16</version>
                <configuration>
                    <reuseForks>false</reuseForks>
                    <forkCount>1</forkCount>
                    <argLine>
                        --illegal-access=permit
                    </argLine>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>
                        --illegal-access=permit
                    </argLine>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Todays log with crash

```
2020-02-06 00:03:40,324 [ 337310]   INFO - j.ide.actions.RevealFileAction - 
Exit code 1 
2020-02-06 00:03:41,023 [ 338009]   INFO - rationStore.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving Project (name=testing-java-junit5, containerState=ACTIVE, componentStore=C:\Users\Paweł\Desktop\Spring Boot Integration Testing\Section 6 Advanced JUnit\testing-java-junit5-dependency-inject) XDebuggerManager took 15 ms 
2020-02-06 00:10:33,092 [ 750078]   WARN - ystem.impl.ActionPopupMenuImpl - 1387ms to fill popup menu ProjectViewPopup 
2020-02-06 00:10:37,479 [ 754465]   INFO - rationStore.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving Project (name=testing-java-junit5, containerState=ACTIVE, componentStore=C:\Users\Paweł\Desktop\Spring Boot Integration Testing\Section 6 Advanced JUnit\testing-java-junit5-dependency-inject) RunManager took 58 ms 
2020-02-06 00:10:37,656 [ 754642]   INFO - ij.compiler.impl.CompileDriver - COMPILATION STARTED (BUILD PROCESS) 
2020-02-06 00:10:38,247 [ 755233]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed. 
2020-02-06 00:10:38,248 [ 755234]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Pawe??\.IntelliJIdea2019.3\system\log\build-log\build.log (The system cannot find the path specified) 
2020-02-06 00:10:38,248 [ 755234]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method) 
2020-02-06 00:10:38,248 [ 755234]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:298) 
2020-02-06 00:10:38,248 [ 755234]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:237) 
2020-02-06 00:10:38,248 [ 755234]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:158) 
2020-02-06 00:10:38,248 [ 755234]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.setFile(FileAppender.java:294) 
2020-02-06 00:10:38,248 [ 755234]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: at org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender.setFile(RollingFileAppender.java:207) 
2020-02-06 00:10:38,248 [ 755234]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.activateOptions(FileAppender.java:165) 
2020-02-06 00:10:38,248 [ 755234]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.activate(PropertySetter.java:307) 
2020-02-06 00:10:38,248 [ 755234]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.setProperties(PropertySetter.java:172) 
2020-02-06 00:10:38,248 [ 755234]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.setProperties(PropertySetter.java:104) 
2020-02-06 00:10:38,249 [ 755235]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseAppender(PropertyConfigurator.java:842) 
2020-02-06 00:10:38,249 [ 755235]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:768) 
2020-02-06 00:10:38,249 [ 755235]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configureRootCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:648) 
2020-02-06 00:10:38,249 [ 755235]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:514) 
2020-02-06 00:10:38,249 [ 755235]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:542) 
2020-02-06 00:10:38,249 [ 755235]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configure(PropertyConfigurator.java:427) 
2020-02-06 00:10:38,249 [ 755235]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.LogSetup.initLoggers(LogSetup.java:51) 
2020-02-06 00:10:38,249 [ 755235]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain.<clinit>(BuildMain.java:61) 
2020-02-06 00:10:38,249 [ 755235]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 
2020-02-06 00:10:38,249 [ 755235]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) 
2020-02-06 00:10:38,249 [ 755235]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) 
2020-02-06 00:10:38,249 [ 755235]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) 
2020-02-06 00:10:38,249 [ 755235]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:58) 
2020-02-06 00:10:38,250 [ 755236]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stdout]: Build process started. Classpath: C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3.2/plugins/java/lib/jps-launcher.jar;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-11.0.6/lib/classes.zip 
2020-02-06 00:10:38,312 [ 755298]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder". 
2020-02-06 00:10:38,312 [ 755298]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation 
2020-02-06 00:10:38,313 [ 755299]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details. 
2020-02-06 00:10:38,619 [ 755605]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred 
2020-02-06 00:10:38,619 [ 755605]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.google.protobuf.UnsafeUtil (file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202019.3.2/lib/protobuf-java-3.5.1.jar) to field java.nio.Buffer.address 
2020-02-06 00:10:38,619 [ 755605]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.google.protobuf.UnsafeUtil 
2020-02-06 00:10:38,619 [ 755605]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations 
2020-02-06 00:10:38,619 [ 755605]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release 
2020-02-06 00:10:41,485 [ 758471]   INFO - lij.compiler.impl.CompilerUtil -     COMPILATION FINISHED (BUILD PROCESS); Errors: 0; warnings: 0 took 3835 ms: 0 min 3sec 
2020-02-06 00:10:41,521 [ 758507]   INFO - s.CompilerReferenceServiceBase - backward reference index reader is opened 
2020-02-06 00:10:41,855 [ 758841]   INFO - ij.execution.JavaExecutionUtil - Agent jars were copied to C:\Users\Paweł\.IntelliJIdea2019.3\system\testAgent 
2020-02-06 00:10:41,934 [ 758920]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed. 
2020-02-06 00:10:41,934 [ 758920]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Pawe??\.IntelliJIdea2019.3\system\log\build-log\build.log (The system cannot find the path specified) 
2020-02-06 00:10:41,935 [ 758921]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method) 
2020-02-06 00:10:41,935 [ 758921]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:298) 
2020-02-06 00:10:41,935 [ 758921]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:237) 
2020-02-06 00:10:41,935 [ 758921]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:158) 
2020-02-06 00:10:41,935 [ 758921]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.setFile(FileAppender.java:294) 
2020-02-06 00:10:41,935 [ 758921]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: at org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender.setFile(RollingFileAppender.java:207) 
2020-02-06 00:10:41,935 [ 758921]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.activateOptions(FileAppender.java:165) 
2020-02-06 00:10:41,935 [ 758921]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.activate(PropertySetter.java:307) 
2020-02-06 00:10:41,935 [ 758921]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.setProperties(PropertySetter.java:172) 
2020-02-06 00:10:41,935 [ 758921]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.setProperties(PropertySetter.java:104) 
2020-02-06 00:10:41,935 [ 758921]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseAppender(PropertyConfigurator.java:842) 
2020-02-06 00:10:41,935 [ 758921]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:768) 
2020-02-06 00:10:41,935 [ 758921]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configureRootCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:648) 
2020-02-06 00:10:41,936 [ 758922]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:514) 
2020-02-06 00:10:41,936 [ 758922]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:542) 
2020-02-06 00:10:41,936 [ 758922]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configure(PropertyConfigurator.java:427) 
2020-02-06 00:10:41,936 [ 758922]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.LogSetup.initLoggers(LogSetup.java:51) 
2020-02-06 00:10:41,936 [ 758922]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain.<clinit>(BuildMain.java:61) 
2020-02-06 00:10:41,936 [ 758922]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 
2020-02-06 00:10:41,936 [ 758922]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) 
2020-02-06 00:10:41,936 [ 758922]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) 
2020-02-06 00:10:41,936 [ 758922]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) 
2020-02-06 00:10:41,936 [ 758922]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:58) 
2020-02-06 00:10:41,937 [ 758923]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stdout]: Build process started. Classpath: C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3.2/plugins/java/lib/jps-launcher.jar;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-11.0.6/lib/classes.zip 
2020-02-06 00:10:41,990 [ 758976]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder". 
2020-02-06 00:10:41,990 [ 758976]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation 
2020-02-06 00:10:41,990 [ 758976]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details. 
2020-02-06 00:10:42,210 [ 759196]   INFO - stframework.SearchForTestsTask - Interrupted function call: accept failed 
java.net.SocketException: Interrupted function call: accept failed
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(PlainSocketImpl.java:159)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:458)
    at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:565)
    at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:533)
    at com.intellij.execution.testframework.SearchForTestsTask.run(SearchForTestsTask.java:91)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:888)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$2(CoreProgressManager.java:163)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:585)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:531)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:59)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:150)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$4.lambda$run$0(CoreProgressManager.java:402)
    at com.intellij.util.ConcurrencyUtil.runUnderThreadName(ConcurrencyUtil.java:221)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$4.run(CoreProgressManager.java:402)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:238)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
2020-02-06 00:10:43,041 [ 760027]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred 
2020-02-06 00:10:43,041 [ 760027]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.google.protobuf.UnsafeUtil (file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202019.3.2/lib/protobuf-java-3.5.1.jar) to field java.nio.Buffer.address 
2020-02-06 00:10:43,041 [ 760027]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.google.protobuf.UnsafeUtil 
2020-02-06 00:10:43,041 [ 760027]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations 
2020-02-06 00:10:43,041 [ 760027]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

Comment: Are there 2 versions of Intellij on your system? If you see the first line, the javagent for coverage is version 2019.3 (in C:/Users) whereas the rest of the plugins are pointed to 2019.2.3 (in C:/Program Files)

Comment: @gyani No, there is one InteliJ version. Just did a quick reinstall now, and all the folder names are accurate now and the error is pretty much the same:

Comment: Can you please share the whole output after test running with coverage. Thanks

Comment: @OlgaKlisho On the left smaller window with the test names, I get: "Test framework quit unexpectedly". The main "Run" windows give me the result as in the question, with: `FATAL ERROR in native method: processing of -javaagent failed

Process finished with exit code 1
Exception in thread "main" `

Comment: Where is located the IDEA's system dir (like C:\Users\userName\.IntelliJIdea2019.3\system)? Does the idea.log (Help | Show Log in Finder) have any java.io.FileNotFoundException? Please share the idea.log if possible

Comment: @OlgaKlisho I've added fresh log with crash. There is one FnFException. Always regarding: `j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Pawe??\.IntelliJIdea2019.3\system\log\build-log\build.log (The system cannot find the path specified)` This could be the problem

Comment: Does your user name include any special symbols? If yes, issue seems to be the duplicate of: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-5941, please see and try the workaround advised there.

Comment: @OlgaKlisho Thank You Olga! It was indeed a problem with local letter symbols in the userName.